# Nested for loop improvement

Tags: r, nested-loops

I'm trying to write a simple population model using nested for loops. I want to project the population 10yrs, and I want to run this projection 100 times. I need the output of each time step and include a counter so I know which year of which iteration the results correspond to. I have an example running using this code, but I was wondering if:

1) There was a more elegant solution to than using the rows<-rows+1 command to reset and advance the counter each time?

2) There is a more elegant solution than for loops to accomplish this?

```
library(VGAM)
popdata<-matrix(nrow=1000,ncol=3)
dimnames(popdata)[[2]]<-c('iteration','year','popsize')
rows<-1
for (iteration in 1:100){
   pop<-50

   for(year in 1:10){
      popdata[rows,1]<-iteration
      popdata[rows,2]<-year

      pop<-rbetabinom(1,pop,0.6)

      popdata[rows,3]<-pop
      rows<-rows+1
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry, fixed it. Do you have a helpful solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the row counter by `(iteration - 1) * 10 + year`. 
You can also clean up the work done in the loop by assigning the iteration and year data outside as you know in advance what these results will be.

This gives something like

```
popdata<-matrix(nrow=1000,ncol=3)
dimnames(popdata)[[2]]<-c('iteration','year','popsize')

# Do the deterministic stuff first
popdata[, 1] <- rep(1:100, each = 10) 
popdata[, 2] <- rep(1:10, times = 100)

for (iteration in 1:100){
   pop<-50

   for(year in 1:10){
      rows <- (iteration - 1) * 10 + yea
      pop<-rbetabinom(1,pop,0.6)
      popdata[rows,3]<-pop
   }
}
```

Because `pop` depends on the previous `pop` it is less easy to simplify the inner loop entirely.
I think the approach would be to generate all your binomial results as a long vector of 1s and 0s.
Then in each loop you would subset the next `pop` elements of that vector.
In the end I don't think that would actually be neater or more readable though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!